# how to remove 0="3" attribute from script tag in yii2?

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

In Yii2 I add my scripts in the main.php file at the end of file before ending body tag like this

```
$this->registerJsFile($this->theme->baseUrl . '/js/scripts.min.js', [
            'depends' => [
                'yii\web\YiiAsset',
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset'
            ], $this::POS_END
        ]);
```

but when i see the check my site on code optimizer website like https://validator.w3.org
it give this error on script tag

Is there any idea how to remove  0="3" attribute.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is not clear .. .. what's the errror .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect syntax of [registerJsFile()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJsFile()-detail) options. Try this:

```
$this->registerJsFile($this->theme->baseUrl . '/js/scripts.min.js', [
    'depends'  => [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
    ],
    'position' => $this::POS_END,
]);
```